# Change RGB color in matplotlib animation

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors

I seems that it is not possible to change colors of a Matplotlib scatter plot through a RGB definition. Am I wrong?

Here is a code (already given in stack overflow) which work with colors indexed in float:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.animation as animation

def main():
    numframes = 100
    numpoints = 10

    color_data = np.random.random((numframes, numpoints))
    x, y, c = np.random.random((3, numpoints))

    fig = plt.figure()
    scat = plt.scatter(x, y, c=c, s=100)

    ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update_plot, frames=range(numframes),
                                  fargs=(color_data, scat))
    plt.show()

def update_plot(i, data, scat):
    scat.set_array(data[i])
    return scat,

main()
```

But if `color_data` is defined through RGB colors, I get an error:

> ValueError: Collections can only map rank 1 arrays

The related code is the following (in this code, I just change the color of one sample each time):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.animation as animation

def main():
    numframes = 100
    numpoints = 10

    rgb_color_data = np.random.random((numpoints, 3))
    x, y = np.random.random((2, numpoints))

    fig = plt.figure()
    scat = plt.scatter(x, y, c=rgb_color_data, s=100) #this work well at this level

    ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update_plot2, frames=range(numframes),
                                  fargs=(rgb_color_data, scat))

    plt.show()

def update_plot2(i,data,scat):
    data[ i%10 ] = np.random.random((3))
    scat.set_array(data) # this fails 
    return scat,

main()
```

Is there a means to use `set_array` with RGB color array?

Answer (score 6):

Not sure what you are trying to achieve. But if you are trying to change the color, why not use the `set_color()` function of `Collection`?

```
def update_plot2(i,data,scat):
    data[ i%10 ] = np.random.random((3))
    scat.set_color(data) # <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    return scat,
```

Comment: Works even better than `scat.set_array()` because `scat.set_color()` takes RGB values!